# Using sequelize-cli with docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

I'm starting to use Docker and I have some questions about build a project using nodejs, sequelize-cli and postgres.

How can I do to exec **npx sequelize-cli db:migrate** inside the container?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
 
WORKDIR /app
 
COPY package*.json ./
 
RUN npm install
 
COPY . .
 
EXPOSE 3000
 
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

And my docker-compose:

```
    version: '3'
    volumes:
      data:
    services:
      db:
        image: postgres:9.6
        env_file: .env
        volumes:
          - data:/var/lib/postgres/data
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=$DB_USE
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD
          - POSTGRES_DB=$DB_NAME
      app:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes: 
          - /app/node_modules
          - .:/app
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Have you tried `docker exec {ContainerNameOrHash} {command you want to run inside} ?

Comment: I chanched the Dockerfile to run an entrypoint with command to make db migrate and worked it

Answer (score 4):

you need to add an entrypoint.sh to run npm commands, something like this:

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
services:
  app:
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "./entrypoint.sh"]
    image: node:10.12.0
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

and with sequelize-cli in your package.json:

```
# entrypoint.sh

npm install
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

just run `docker-compose run --rm app npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`

or... if you have the service already running, you could simply login to the container (`docker-compose exec app bash`) and run the command inside your running container (`npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`)

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile you can add:

```
RUN npm install -g sequelize-cli
```

and then `docker exec app sequelize db:migrate --env production`